# Spring factory static method

Tags: java, spring

изучаю документацию по Spring, связанную с Beans, предоставлен следующий код:

```
public class ClientService {
    private static ClientService clientService = new ClientService();
    private ClientService() {}

    public static ClientService createInstance() {
        return clientService;
    }
}

<bean id="clientService"
    class="examples.ClientService"
    factory-method="createInstance"/>
```

Подскажите:

1. Зачем внутри класса мы создаем статическое поле с объектом этого-же класса?
2. Для чего нужна статическая реализация бина, если есть конструкторы и геттеры(я предполагаю, что это позволит нам по необходимости создавать или не создавать зависимость для всех будующих объектов)?

Comment: знаете, что такое область видимости (scope) и что такое синглтон (как паттерн и как область видимости)?

Comment: знаю, что по умолчанию скопе стоит такой, что создает единичный объект (как раз синглтон получается), как паттерн тоже знаю в виде, когда мы прописываем конструктор с проверкой на существование объекта, если объект есть - его и возвращаем, если объекта нет - создаем

Comment: ну вот вы привели пример классического синглтона во всех смыслах этого слова, коим и является бин.

Comment: Дмитрий, благодарю за ответ, я верно понял, что это необходимо для создания зависимости, которая будет существовать в единственном экземпляре для всех объектов этого класса?